# Laravel Eloquent query to check how many siblings student have

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have two tables

```
**students :**
id
family_id
name

**family :**
id
father_name
father_civil_id
contact_no
```

both tables are connected using family_id, i want to get how many Brothers/Sisters each students have(with name of sibling) using eloquent.
can you please help me, with controller/model/view.

Comment: you can use relationship

Comment: Are Brothers/Sisters students too?

Comment: @TsaiKoga yes all are in student table.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a Student and Family model. Then you have several ways to do it.

Here are the two easiest ones I can guess with the information you provided.

### Without relationship

**Controller**

```php
Student::where('family_id', $family_id)->get();
```

### HasMany relationship

**Family model**

```php
class Family extends Model
{
    // Since Laravel will expect your table to be 'families'
    protected $table = 'family';

    public function students()
    {
         return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```php
 $family = Family::with('students')->inRandomOrder()->first();
 $siblings = $family->students;
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to call $sibling names in view?

Comment: `return view('your-view')->with('siblings, $siblings);` should do the trick.
You can see more on [Laravel's view documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: please check;
Controller:   $showdata = Student::find($id); //to find all students
$sibling=Student::where('family_id', $family_id)->get();
return View('students.profile')->with('showdata', $showdata)->with('sibling', $sibling);
** i got error $family_id not defined, can you please tell me why?

Comment: Because you don't have `$family_id` defined in your code. It was just for the example :)

Comment: why you have declared $siblings = $family->students; in has many controller?

Comment: To make you understand better the things I wanted to explain

Answer (score 0):

In Students Model:

```
public function family() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Family');
}

public function getSiblings() {
    return $this->family->students;
}
```

So you can call it by your students:

```
$student->getSiblings();
```

Comment: can you please tell me ; $student->getSiblings(); how to save this in controller and show in view?

Comment: with your code i get this error, please check;
Class 'App\Models\Family' not found"

Comment: the class depend on your family model namespace, I think yours are 'App\Family'

Comment: how to access sibling if there is any on each student profile in view?

Comment: In your controller action ```profile``` you can use ```$student = Student::find($id); ```, and return to render ```return view("profile", compact('student'));``` . And in your profile view, you can just use ```$student->getSiblings()```

Comment: My Controller:
$showdata = Student::find($id);
return View('students.profile' ,compact('showdata');
My Student Model:
class student extends Model
{
 public function family() {
  return $this->belongsTo(family::class,'family_id'); }

public function getSiblings() {
    return $this->family->students;
}}
My profile View:
Brother Sisters :{{$showdata->getSiblings()}}
_________
can you please suggest what is wrong?

Comment: getSiblings() is a Eloquent Collection, you need to loop display their fields

Comment: can you please write code how, i tried for each loop but got error. is everything else ok in code?

Comment: that means ```getSiblings()``` return null inside,Try to use php artisan tinker, post the ```Student::find()->getSiblings()```  to see what returns